# Message isn't getting posted to Private Channel in Slack

Tags: javascript, api, slack, slack-api

I am trying to create a slackbot for private channel.I have set it up as an app and created a bot. But, whenI am trying to post the message in private channel it's not working. It works for the public channels. I have added the app/bot in the private channel. I am using Bot User OAuth Access Token in my code.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const bot = new SlackBot({
  token: 'already-given',
  name: 'bot'
});

// Start Handler
bot.on('start', () => {
  const params = {
    icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
  };

  bot.postMessageToChannel(
    'pvtchannel',
    'I will assign a member soon!',
    params
  );
});

// Error Handle
bot.on('error', err => console.log(err));

// Message Handler
bot.on('message', data => {
  if (data.type !== 'message') {
    return;
  }

  handleMessage(data.text);
});

// Response to Data
function handleMessage(message) {
  if (message.includes('newspin')) {
    newSpin();

  } else (message.includes('help')) {
    runHelp();
  }
}

// Pick a team member randomly
function newSpin() {

    const params = {
      icon_emoji: ':laughing:'
    };
    var members=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'];
    var assignee = members[Math.floor(Math.random()*members.length)];

      bot.postMessageToChannel('pvtchannel', `It's ${assignee}'s turn today!`, params);


}



// Show Help Text
function runHelp() {
  const params = {
    icon_emoji: ':question:'
  };

  bot.postMessageToChannel(
    'pvtchannel',
    `Type @bot with either 'newspin' for new spinning again,
    params
  );
}
```

Is this how we need to post messages to private channel?

```
bot.postMessageToChannel('pvtchannel', 'It's ${assignee}'s turn today!', params);
```

I am confused if I need to add anything before the pvtchannel as it's private.

Comment: Is this the live code? Because a large part of it is interpreted as text string, not code and therefore not executed. you can see it from Stackoverflow's text coloring. all the red text is not code. the problem is here: `bot.postMessageToChannel(
    'pvtchannel',`

Comment: If that's not it you want to add some logging for the response of the Slack API. It will usually tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Yes, this is the live code and it's working for public channels. But here "pvtchannel" means I am including a private channel. It works if the channel is public, but doesn't if it's private. I think to post in private channel I need to add something before the "pvtchannel"  ` bot.postMessageToChannel( 'pvtchannel', `

Comment: ok. I corrected your formatting. No, posting to private channels should not require any additional command. Again, I would add logging of the API response to get more information about potential errors.

Comment: @ErikKalkokenThanks for that! Unfortunately, I am not getting any error while running the code. It's just not posting it in a private channel. If I replace the "pvtchannel" with a public channel the messages are getting posted in the public channel! I was using this: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: the endpoint `chat.postMessage` always returns a response as JSON array. Its either a copy of the posted message or info about the error. What do you get?